# What does `M` in the Kotlin version mean?

Tags: kotlin

The preview version of Kotlin includes `M`, like `1.4-M2`.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pulls?q=is%3Aclosed+milestone%3A1.4
Stands for Milestone 2.  `<major>.<minor> <qualifier>`

It is a qualifier, which means that it is a preview release before the final 1.4 release.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN400
https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/02/04/apache-maven-how-version-comparison-works/